# What's the deal with this Low Quality Posts review/audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just came across a [Low Quality Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20550628) that I find quite strange.

The review system tells me:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

And so I examined it carefully: There's a link to some Angular plugin in the post and the question is about that very Angular plugin, so that doesn't look like spam to me. But to be sure and get a better picture of the answer in its context I clicked through to the view of the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407604/what-is-angular-platform-browser). There I realized that the answer post to be reviewed doesn't actually exist (anymore).

So, I guess, that review is actually an audit and that I would fail if I'd click *Looks OK*. But I can't see why I shouldn't click *Looks OK*.

The question is in essence: "What's that Angular plugin doing". And that answer lists a few things that plugin does and includes a link to that plugin. Might be a non-great answer to a non-great question, but [according to a highly voted meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) about the topic, it should surely be reviewed as *Looks OK*.

Could someone let me know where the flaw in my reasoning here is?

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that it seems this plugin is part of the official Angular (assuming from the facts that angular.io is the official Website for Angular 2+ and the package name `@angular/platform-browser`). So it is not spam from my point of view (still low-quality, but at least it points to the offical website/docs).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That particular post was deleted because a user had raised a spam flag on it. Given that the post was deleted after receiving a spam flag, it was chosen as an audit and the warning was added to it.

I've cleared the spam flag (as it is not spam), and undeleted the post, thereby removing the post as an audit. I also unbanned the reviewer who had failed that audit.

As for your reasoning, it is correct. That surely should be reviewed as Looks Ok.

Comment: "I also unbanned the reviewer who had failed that audit"... volunteer, they said, it will be fun!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque getting banned is cute, but have you got off site insults, death threats or a random dude come to your office to beat you up, for volunteering here? That's the real fun.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I was just talking bout the fun parts of moderating on Stack Overflow, because you mentioned that they said volunteering is fun ;)

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for clarifying. I was actually looking at it from the POV of the volunteer grunts that work the review queues... but I understand your point... Here, have a hug, the world can be a cold place! ;)